# What is a good reference on simulating ordinal random variables?

Tags: categorical-data, simulation, ordinal-data

I'm interested in any references for simulating ordinal random variables to be used in a Bayesian (multilevel) analysis.

Comment: Basically, any text for categorical data analysis has the reference. Could you be a bit more detailed, that is, do you have any specific model in mind? Otherwise these are good references: Agresti, A. (2002). Categorical Data Analysis, John Wiley. Gelman, A. and Hill, J. (2007). Data Analysis Using Hierarchical/Multilevel Models, Cambridge University Press.

Comment: You can threshold continuous data. For example, the model underlying ordinal logistic regression (a.k.a. the proportional odds model) is equivalent to thresholding logistically distributed variables with mean given by the regression function.